# I am getting Run-time error 9

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am making project in which table that has change need to be copied to another sheet, it needs to be synchronized data transfer trough sheets, if we fill one form data needs to be transferred to all sheets.

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("C4:E8")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

       Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D4:D8").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Range("D4:D8")


    'MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed." Just for code testing don't look at it 

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: in which Worksheet module do you have this code ?

Comment: in which Worksheet module do you have this code ? What do you mean by it ? I am just starting my way in VBA

Comment: One of your sheet names is misspelled.  It does not match the sheet names on the tabs.  Double check there are not spaces or other hidden characters.

Comment: They are spelled differently, but in code they are right, maybe will help fact that i have to use excel 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have 2 worksheets only. Put the following code on the first worksheet, here:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("More than 1!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set KeyCells = Range("C4:E8")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets(1).Range("C4:E8").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("C4:E8")
    End If

End Sub
```

Upon a change of the data in `C4:E8`, it would be copied to the second worksheet.

---

If you put it on the second worksheet, this will produce a nice recursion error. Try it out, if you wish! :)

Edit:
This question has plenty of ways to do it. This is a way with looping through the cells:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells    As Range
    Dim rngCell     As Range

    Set KeyCells = Worksheets(1).Range("C4:E8")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        For Each rngCell In KeyCells
            Worksheets(2).Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column) = rngCell
        Next rngCell
    End If

End Sub
```

However it will not work well, if you have merged cells either in `worksheets(1)` or `worksheets(2)`

Comment: Doesn't work but may it be that in sheet 1 its 3 merged cells per 1 row and in sheet 2 there is not?

Comment: @JānisAnerauds - unmerge and try! :)

Comment: @JānisAnerauds - that's because you select more than one cell. See the code again! :)

Comment: now it gives me Compile error: Variable not defined, if what i have my info as txt

Answer (score 0):

After using

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Dim KeyCells    As Range
Dim rngCell     As Range

Set KeyCells = Worksheets(1).Range("C4:E8")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
    For Each rngCell In KeyCells
        Worksheets(2).Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column) = rngCell
    Next rngCell
End If
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVUd0.png)